# Item renderer data binding in spark list control

Tags: list, mobile, air, flex-spark, renderer

Please find my code below. I need to show some data in label that is coming from database. I do set data provider property:

```
    var result:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(stmt.getResult().data);
            selected_category_list.dataProvider = result;

<s:List id="selected_category_list" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
        change="selected_category_list_changeHandler(event)" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:HGroup paddingLeft="2">
                <s:Image source="assets/gesture_images/arms/44.png" width="50" height="50" />
                <s:Label text="{data.meaning}" width="125"/>
            </s:HGroup>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
```

it shows an error--> "Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
1120: Access of undefined property data" on this line Label text="{data.meaning}"

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In `<fx:Component>`, you must put `<s:ItemRenderer>`.
So your itemRenderer is :

```
<s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:ItemRenderer>
            <s:HGroup paddingLeft="2">
                <s:Image source="assets/gesture_images/arms/44.png" width="50" height="50" />
                <s:Label text="{data.meaning}" width="125"/>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:ItemRendere>
    </fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
```